# Led must be mounted SINK or SOURCE so as not to interfere with communications?

Tags: led, sourcing, sinking

I used 3.3v microcontroller. I want to add TX LED and RX LED communication on RS232, RS485, 
TTL/CMOS.

My question:

Led communication must be mounted as SINKING or SOURCING on I/O microcontroller for avoid interfere in communications?

Picture in here: [Datasheet](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3-9VxQAPMVMd25OSFhfTHZJTDA/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Whats your question?

Comment: Led communication must be mounted as SINK(pull down) or SOURCE(pull up) on I/O microcontroller for avoid interfere in communications?

Comment: What about your set-up would make it interfere either way?

Comment: Are you asking which, sink or source? Or, sink/source, versus something else? What exactly do you mean by "SINK" or "SOURCE"? How about a schematic?

Comment: The question is not pointeless; it's entirely possible that a line driver drives "high" or "low" better than in the other direction - however, changing the arrangement will change the "sense" of when the LED is on, which may not be desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RX and TX lines at TTL signals** between the μC and the line driver IC*** is a good place to connect the LED indicators.  There's no good reason to connect the LEDs to RS-232 lines.  RS-485 lines are bidirectional, so the LEDs alone wouldn't tell if the data is TX or RX on RS485.

** 0 to 3.3V serial
*** RS-232 or RS-485 line driver, and such

Back to TTL signals.  You can connect the LED between signals and GND **, or between signal and Vcc ***.  Either would work as long as the LED current is low enough (limited by a series resistor).  LEDs add some capacitance, which might be a problem at high speeds above, say, 1M bits per second.

** source in the O.P. terminology
*** sink